# How to handle appcenter login error in shell script?

Tags: ios, shell, terminal, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am using the below script for publishing the ipa to appcenter.

```
ipaPath=<PATH TO MY IPA FILE>
echo "Found ipa at $ipaPath"

if [[ -z ${ipaPath} ]]

then

    echo "No ipas were found, skip publishing to App Center"

else

    appcenter login 
    appcenter distribute release \
        --group Collaborators \
        --file "${ipaPath}" \
        --release-notes 'App submission' \
        --app <username_or_organization>/<application_identifier> \
        --quiet
fi
```

I need to exit if the login is failed and don't want to run the distribute command. how to check the login status and handle the error?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to capture the result of `appcenter login` into a variable, then search the variable contents for a specific string (or lack of). For example:

```
reply="$(appcenter login --token ${token})"

if [[ $reply == *"Error"* ]]; then
  echo "A problem occurred! ${reply}"
else
  appcenter distribute release
  ...
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! The above solution works fine but I need to capture the result of appcenter login without using the token. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: @BalaMurugan Not that know of. I am unable to achieve silent login to appcenter without using the `--token` option. When using `-p` and `-u` options, an error states that it is a "interactive environment". Without any options, I am taken to the website and supplied with a token, so it seems the token is required.